# Why is any one Wirtinger relation a consequence of the remainder?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

As the question title suggests, how do I see that any one Wirtinger relation is a consequence of the remainder?

Comment: There is nothing unclear about this question. Every crossing of a knot diagram yields one relation for the Wirtinger presentation of the knot group. It seems that one of these relations is redundant and thus can be omitted from the presentation, and the question is asking why.

Comment: If you look at the knot diagram from above and imagine a loop beneath it and circling it, then the loop is contractible in the space  less the knot, but from above  in this contraction the loop goes through each crossing. That is how I **see** it. A more formal proof is probably better using groupoids, but that is not to general taste.

Comment: Why don't you write this up as an answer?